# Simple Javascript Paginator with appendChild turning into undefined

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have looked at this a bit, so I'm throwing it out here. I wanted to make my own simple pagination for a large table on a website, and hit a roadblock.  Here's my code/markup:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  table_pagers = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination");

  paginate_tables(table_pagers);
});

function paginate_tables(table_pagers) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= table_pagers.length - 1; i++) {
    table_pagers[i].innerHTML = make_nums(table_pagers[i]);
  }
};

function make_nums(table_sibling) {
  table = table_sibling.previousElementSibling.children[1];
  nums = table.childElementCount / 10;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = i;
    a.href = "\'#\'"
    li.appendChild(a);
    table_sibling.appendChild(li);
  }
};
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ul class="pagination">
</ul>
```

The problem that is boggling ( I tried both insert adjacentHTML and appendChild ) Is that this code will insert the list items perfectly, but once it exits the make_nums function, the entire set of li's turn into undefined.

Alternatively if I substitute table in, they all append perfectly to the end of the table, but of course they need to be in the the ul, not the table.  What the heck am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
    table_pagers[i].innerHTML = make_nums(table_pagers[i]);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your `make_nums` function doesn't return any specific value, so the result of calling it is `undefined`. Then you're using that to replace the content of the list.

Your function already adds the elements to the list, so there's no reason to set `innerHTML`; just remove the underscored part above:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var table_pagers = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination");

  paginate_tables(table_pagers);
});

function paginate_tables(table_pagers) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= table_pagers.length - 1; i++) {
    make_nums(table_pagers[i]);
  }
};

function make_nums(table_sibling) {
  var table = table_sibling.previousElementSibling.children[1];
  var nums = table.childElementCount / 10;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = i;
    a.href = "\'#\'"
    li.appendChild(a);
    table_sibling.appendChild(li);
  }
};
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ul class="pagination">
</ul>
```

---

Side note: Your code was also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Be sure to declare your variables. I've added declarations for `table_pagers`, `table`, and `nums` above.

Comment: O god.  Working too much with ruby lately on those "var" declarations. I just couldn't see past my own nose on this one. I should get a linter for ST3.  It's late. Thanks a ton for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as suggested by T.J Crowder the problem is in this line:

```
table_pagers[i].innerHTML = make_nums(table_pagers[i]);
```

Here, you are seting the innerHTML while you have already added li's to ul inside make_nums() function.

As a side note, while it is good to declare variables `table, nums` with var inside make_nums() function, they look irrelevant to the function. Do you really need them? If not you can clean them up!

Comment: Yeah this is a little bit of a brute force exercise (still in my first year of developing), I'm dealing with 680 table rows, and so make_nums generates 1-68 paginators, which I originally planned on hiding and showing.. I think I see a refactor already but I'm continuing on this path until I get all the way to green.

Comment: Wish you all the best!